# :active class not working

Tags: html, css

I used :after and :before psuedo elements to have border when hover over the nav links. I have been trying to have same hover border effect in :active psuedo classe so can some tell me how to do that. Here's my code:

```css
nav ul .u {
  position: relative;
  color: f4f4f4;
}
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  transition: width .2s;
}
nav ul li a:after {
  left: 10%;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
nav ul li a:before {
  right: 10%;
  top: -5px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #F4F4F4;
}
nav ul li a:hover:before,
nav ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 80%;
}
nav ul .active a:after,
nav ul .active a:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  transition: width .3s;
}
nav ul .active a:after {
  left: 10%;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
nav ul .active a:before {
  right: 10%;
  top: -5px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a class="u" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="u" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="u" href="#">Specials</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This seems a little overboard. Why don't you just use normal hover styles.

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
nav ul li a:active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

to your css. And as per the definition of :active class says, whenever the user would mouseclick over your links, he would see the color of link changing to yellow.

For more reference about active class, one can go through this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive

Comment: Thanks but not working. I want to get the same effect in active state that I get on hover.

Comment: @TejenderSingh: It seems to be working in the plunk. check here: http://plnkr.co/edit/chIunu?p=preview

Comment: It was already working on hover but not in active state. Actually, I want same yellow border on the top and bottom of links when they are active.

Comment: Do you understand what active means?

Comment: @Paran0a: Are you asking me?

Comment: @TejenderSingh: when you have clicked on any element, then, it goes into ":visited: state, which is applicable only to "anchor" tags. ":active" class is triggered only when the user clicks over the anchor, and releases the mouse, just for that fraction. You might want to do the same thing on ":visited" psuedo class.

Comment: @Shivi sorry I was asking the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong Usage.

**Please check the definition for after:**
::after is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML).

You can use normal hover styling for your requirement.